# About Laravel get method routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Can laravel support such get method routing?

```
Route::get('/users/{id}/posts?num={num}','SomeController@SomeMethod');
```

Here,`id` is a parameter in url and `num` is another parameter appended after url. `SomeMethod` accept two parameters `id` and `num`.

I did do some google.But all I got is about

```
Route::get('/users/{id}/posts/{num}','SomeController@SomeMethod');
```

Can laravel support such get routing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. Change the route to:

```
Route::get('/users/{id}/posts','SomeController@someMethod');
```

You controller method will look like this:

```
public function someMethod($id)
{
    $num = request('num');
```

Then URL like this one will pass to the method and you'll get values of `id` and `num`:

```
/users/2/posts?num=78
```